# how to add my scheduler to linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling

I'm working on a research on linux kernel. I should add a scheduler algorithm to linux kernel, like SJF, SRT and any other algorithms. After some searches I found that linux kernel has tow schedulers: CFS and real-time scheduler.
but what is difference between this tow scheduler? How should write my scheduler code? where I should add my scheduler code, CFS or real-time? should I do this work before compiling linux kernel? and any other things that I need to do this work...
I'm using linux kernel 3.15.6.

Comment: Do some research on the web. Ask on http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: I've searched alot ! but I didn't find any useful page.

Comment: Study also the kernel source code, see http://kernel.org/

Comment: The kernel source has a [Documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation?id=refs/tags/v3.16.1) subdirectory. Read it.