# CFS vs Real-time scheduler

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

what is difference between CFS and real-time scheduler in linux kernel? and where is their source code in linux kernel?

Comment: seems to be a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380139/how-to-add-my-scheduler-to-linux-kernel

Comment: if you know the answer, say it on that post!